How do I override Intellij plugin BasePlatformTestCase to use a different plugin.xml file when running tests
When developing an intellij plugin I have a plugin.xml file with certain postStartupActivity entries that slow down and freeze up the tests. If I remove this entry the tests pass immediately. Its not necessary this runs for the tests.. how can I remove this specifically when running tests.
Example plugin.xml:
<idea-plugin url="https://github.com/mycompany/myplugin"  require-restart="true" >

    <id>com.mycompany.myplugin</id>
    <name>My Plugin</name>
    <extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
        <applicationConfigurable
                parentId="appearance"
                groupWeight="40"
                instance="com.mycompany.MyConfigurable"
                id="my.id"
                displayName="My Plugin"/>

        <applicationService serviceImplementation="com.mycompany.MyMainService"/>

        <!-- COMMENTING OUT THIS PROBLEM ACTIVITY LETS TEST RUN -->
        <!-- HOW DO I prevent this from loading... and/or REPLACE THIS FILE with one that doesnt contain this entry -->
        <postStartupActivity implementation="com.mycompany.SlowStartupActivity"/>

    </extensions>
</idea-plugin>

example test
// HANGS if i don't comment above postStartupActivity
public class MyTest extends BasePlatformTestCase {  
    @Test
    public void aTest(){
        assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}

Edit:
As a workaround, I added in a check for a test specific environment variable that skips loading the slow parts of the code
    public class SlowStartupActivity implements ProjectActivity {
        @Override
        public Object execute(@NotNull Project project, @NotNull Continuation<? super Unit> continuation) {

            if(!Objects.equals(System.getenv("MY_TEST_FLAG"), "")){
               //skip loading
               return;
            }
            // do slow long running thing
 
            return;
        } 
        // ...
    }

